# How do I enable HTTPS in Docker Container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ssl, https, amazon-ecs

I have deployed my linux container in AWS ECS, and I can access it over port 80 by using an AWS load balancer.

How do I make them visible by adding certificate on 443. I have tried just exposing the port, but I also need to add the certificate. I cant use docker-compose as  AWS ECS doesn't support that and I need to add everything in the single application **Dockerfile**.

What are the steps for adding the certificate in a **dockerfile**?

My dockerfile looks like this now

```
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8000
CMD [ "node", "env.js"]
```

Comment: Do you really need end-to-end ssl encryption? Usually you terminate HTTPS  on your LB, then you have just HTTP.

Comment: yeah i need end-2-end ssl, actually the target group for application load balancer in AWS supports 2 protocol, HTTP and HTTPS, i will have to use https to connect to container to avoid any security mishaps. Is there any way to  acces container application over HTTPS

Comment: I see. Sure there is. You need self-signed certificate on your container. Not sure if `node:10` does this. If not then you have to pair it with `nginx` to serve the https and proxy to your node container.

Comment: i can use any node version above 10 but how do configure this in a single Dockerfile with nginx, do you have any examples for other languages i can refer that

Comment: Sadly, don't know of any particular tutorial for node, though there are plenty for nginx.

Comment: Could you share that i will just use that reference.

Comment: I remember I was using [this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-18-04) successful. Its not for containers specifically, but the setups should be similar.

Comment: I will try and let you know if this works out somehow, in meanwhile if you find anything with containers point of view, please share here and thank you.